# $\nu(A) := \int_{\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R} \int_{S^1} \mathbf{1}_{A}(|x|w,z)\, d\sigma(w)\, d\mu(x,z)$ is $\sigma$-additive

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, borel-measures

Following [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4476859/425395) by Christophe, I'm trying to show that $\nu$ defined by $$\nu(A) := \int_{\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R} \int_{S^1} \mathbf{1}_{A}(|x|w,z) \,d\sigma(w)\, d\mu(x,z)$$ is a Borel measure on $\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R$. It is enough to check $\sigma$-additivity, i.e., if $\{A_i\}$ is a countable collection of disjoint sets in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R$, then $$\nu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \nu(A_i) $$

---

**My work:** Suppose $A = \cup_i A_i$ where $\{A_i\}$ are disjoint sets in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R$. We have
\begin{align*}
\nu(A) &= \int_{\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R} \Big(\int_{S^1} \mathbf{1}_{\cup_i A_i}(|x|w,z)\,  d\sigma(w) \Big)\, d\mu(x,z)\\
&= \int_{\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R} \Big(\int_{S^1} \int_{\Bbb N} \mathbf{1}_{A_i}(|x|w,z)\,d\lambda(i)\,  d\sigma(w) \Big)\, d\mu(x,z)\\
&= \int_{\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R} \Big(\int_{\Bbb N} \int_{S^1} \mathbf{1}_{A_i}(|x|w,z)\,  d\sigma(w)\, d\lambda(i) \Big)\, d\mu(x,z)\\
&= \int_{\Bbb N} \Big(\int_{\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R} \int_{S^1} \mathbf{1}_{A_i}(|x|w,z)\,  d\sigma(w) \, d\mu(x,z) \Big)\, d\lambda(i)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \nu(A_i)
\end{align*}
where $\lambda$ is the counting measure on $\Bbb N$. Since all the involved spaces are $\sigma$-finite, the product measure on their cartesian product is uniquely determined (and so the above integrals make sense.)

I have used [Tonelli's theorem for non-negative measurable functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli%27s_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_functions) as stated here for the above computation. It *remains to check* that the function $h: (\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R) \times S^1 \times \Bbb N \to \Bbb C$ defined by $$h((x,z),w, i) = \mathbf{1}_{A_i}(|x|w,z)$$ is **Borel measurable** on $(\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R) \times S^1 \times \Bbb N$. Could someone kindly help me complete the proof? Thank you!

Comment: You have to measurabiltiy of $$h((x,z),w, i) = \mathbf{1}_{A_i}(|x|w,z)\,$$  on $(\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R) \times S^1 \times \Bbb N$.  $d\lambda_i$ factor in the definition of $h$ does not make sense.

Comment: $ \mathbf{1}_{A_i}(|x|w,z)$ is the composition oif $1_{A_i}$ with the continuous map $(x,w,z,i) \to  (|x|w,z,i)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $T : (x,z,w) \mapsto (|x|w,z)$ from $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{S}_1$ to $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ is continuous hence Borel-measurable. The function $h$ takes values in $\{0,1\}$, and
$$h^{-1}\{1\} = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}T^{-1}(A_i) \times \{i\}$$
is a Borel subset. Hence $h$ is Borel-measurable.